# Multiple FormsAuthenticationTicket tickets MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formsauthenticationticket

I am using FormsAuthenticationTicket in my app. What I have is two different user types, super admin and then ordinary user.

The super admin can impersonate the ordinary user. I would like to have multiple FormsAuthenticationTicket instances, can I have that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as ASP.NET Forms Authentication mechanism is concerned, there are absolutely no issues with a single instance . Users are tracked with cookies and requests are stateless. Databases also handle concurrency pretty well.

You can use forms authentication and multiple sessions. Your post seemed to say that two people using the same forms authentication account would share the same session and would cause problems. In fact, I can't understand what your point about Multiple instances of Authentication ticket was, because two users logging in won't share the same session.

Comment: What I want is one user having two different tokens.